# Yii2 smtp email is not working on godaddy

Tags: yii2, smtp

I have deploy a Yii2 website from one server to godaddy. Its showing an error :-

```
'If you receive error " Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection refused #111] "'
```

I have set the mail configs below:-

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 't********m@gmail.com',
            'password' => '***************',
            'port' => '465',
            'encryption' => 'tls', //depends if you need it
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 3):

I resolved it by just commenting the transport tag as below:-

```
'mailer' => [
    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
    'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
    //'transport' => [
      //  'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
       // 'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
       // 'username' => 't********m@gmail.com',
       // 'password' => '***************',
       // 'port' => '465',
       // 'encryption' => 'tls', //depends if you need it
    // ],
],
```

Comment: How does it even work if sender, host, user-password stuff is commented here?

Comment: Don't know. But I think as we have php mail(mail()) function doesn't need any credentials then it also have not to ask for it.